# Magento2: Showing price "from" on configurable products

Tags: magento2, category, template, theme

Not sure if this is a simple setting or something I am missing but it is really bugging me. Say I have a configurable product that has different prices for each variation of £10, £20 and £30. When looking in the category view it just shows £10 next to the product. Rather than "from £10". Is there a way of adding that for products that have more than one price? Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if this is a bug possibly fixed in versions since 2.0.2 or if this is just the way Magento 2 behaves?

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question yesterday and it got closed (for some reason). So I saw your question as related and decided to answer it.

It's not a complete solution yet, but this will help you add "Price from:" next to configurable products. Further logic can and **should** be added so the text only shows if there are simple products with different prices  associated to the configurable.

This is what I did (Magento 2.2):

Copy

> /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

to

> /app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

And add `'display_label' => __('Price from:'),` to this block od code:

```
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'display_label'     => __('Price from:'),
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can check my complete solution here: [Add "Price from" to configurable products which contain different price simple products - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211557/add-price-from-to-configurable-products-which-contain-different-price-simple-p/212115#212115)