# The word "From" missing for configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

In my Magento 2 instance I have a few configurable products however on the frontend the word "From" is missing before the price on both the listing and detail pages of the catalog.

The actual configurable products function as expected eg the price changes when the user selects different options.

Could someone advise if there is a setting which needs to be enabled for the wording "From" to be shown on 1st page load

Comment: There is no setting for this in admin. I faced a similar issue not long ago. You can check what I did to solve this here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211557/add-price-from-to-configurable-products-which-contain-different-price-simple-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by extending `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice` with functions for getting min/max final price of configurable products and inserting the label only when needed (when there are simple products with different prices inside the configurable).

Gonna post my solution for others that might need help with this:

> {Vendor}/{Module}/etc/di.xml

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Pricing\Price;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class FinalPrice extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice
{

    protected $priceResolver;

    protected $maxFinalAmount;

    protected $minFinalAmount;

    protected $lowestPriceOptionsProvider;

    protected $configurableType;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface $saleableItem,
        $quantity,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Adjustment\CalculatorInterface $calculator,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\PriceResolverInterface $priceResolver,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\LowestPriceOptionsProviderInterface $lowestPriceOptionsProvider = null,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurableType
    ) {
        parent::__construct($saleableItem, $quantity, $calculator, $priceCurrency, $priceResolver);
        $this->priceResolver = $priceResolver;
        $this->lowestPriceOptionsProvider = $lowestPriceOptionsProvider ?:
        ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\LowestPriceOptionsProviderInterface::class);
        $this->configurableType = $configurableType ?:
        ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::class);
    }

    public function getMaxFinalAmount()
    {
        if (null === $this->maxFinalAmount) {
            $this->maxFinalAmount = $this->doGetMaxFinalAmount() ?: false;
        }
        return $this->maxFinalAmount;
    }

    protected function doGetMaxFinalAmount()
    {
        $maxAmount = null;
        $usedProducts = $this->configurableType->getUsedProducts($this->product);

        foreach ($usedProducts as $product) {
            $childPriceAmount = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount();
            if (!$maxAmount || ($childPriceAmount->getValue() > $maxAmount->getValue())) {
                $maxAmount = $childPriceAmount;
            }
        }
        return $maxAmount;
    }

    public function getMinFinalAmount()
    {
        if (null === $this->minFinalAmount) {
            $this->minFinalAmount = $this->doGetMinFinalAmount() ?: parent::getAmount();
        }
        return $this->minFinalAmount;
    }

    protected function doGetMinFinalAmount()
    {
        $minAmount = null;
        $usedProducts = $this->lowestPriceOptionsProvider->getProducts($this->product);

        foreach ($usedProducts as $product) {
            $childPriceAmount = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount();
            if (!$minAmount || ($childPriceAmount->getValue() < $minAmount->getValue())) {
                $minAmount = $childPriceAmount;
            }
        }
        return $minAmount;
    }
}
```

Then you can call the new function getMinFinalAmount and getMaxFinalAmount from your custom:

> .../Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
>
> $minAmount = $finalPriceModel->getMinFinalAmount(); $maxAmount =
>   $finalPriceModel->getMaxFinalAmount();

And display the label where you want like this:

```
<?php if ($minAmount < $maxAmount) { ?>
    <span class="price-label"><?php echo __('Price from:') ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

All that's left is to use JS to hide the Price from label when a simple configuration is selected.

---

Answer is copied from Web .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, isnt this functionality native in Magento? It is in Magento 1

Comment: Hi , This is in magento 2 but for that you should have to set multiple prices with configurable Product  from admin so it will automatically use From $Price  with product .
if my answer helped me please accept this answer as solution .