# Magento 2 How to change label for Configurable Product "As low as"?

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, configurable-price

I want to change "As low as" Price label for Configurable products.

Can anyone know how to change this label?

[image]

Comment: How u change this label ?

Comment: Yes, I have changed this label.

Comment: How can u write down the steps please

Comment: You can refer below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below link for change the label. M2 has configurable product extension and label should be render from the template file.

[Please refer this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211557/add-price-from-to-configurable-products-which-contain-different-price-simple-p)

Answer (score 1):

You can create CSV file to your custom theme and add translate it as per your need.

> Create CSV file at app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv

```
'As low as','As max As'
```

**Deploy static content and clear cache.**

Answer (score 0):

Edit your translation file, find line from

> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/i18n/en_US.csv
>   then enter
>
> **`'As low as' 'your custom label text`**

run **`cache:flush`**

Comment: i don't want to do it using csv file i want to change in phtml or block file where it comes from and i can't able to find that file.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232410/how-can-i-remove-as-low-as-in-magento-2-2-4